# Convert sorted floating point numbers into alphabetically sorted strings

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to convert *C++* double precision numbers into strings in such a way that sorting the strings alphabetically will deliver the same order as sorting the numbers arithmetically.

I'm considering using a fixed size integer and decimal part. For instance:

```
1.5 < 11.0, as well as alphabetically 0001.5000 < 0011.0000
```

However, this method has several problems (such as range limitation). Is there any better method? Does converting *doubles* into *bitsets* meet the requirements?

Comment: How are you representing huge numbers in your string, in exponential notation or fully filled out, e.g. would 1E100 be a string 100 characters long, or just "1E100" or "1.0E+100" or ???

Comment: @franji1 I won't be able to represent huge numbers with my basic approach.

Comment: While it's a joke RFC, I wonder if the techniques outlined in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2550 would help you :)

Comment: Would [hexadecimal floating-point format](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2020/07/28/hexadecimal-floating-point/) be acceptable?

Comment: Can you assume `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559`? That would simplify the answer.

Comment: So everything is in decimal notation, with or without sign, with or without a decimal point (e.g. -1, -1., -1.0, -1.00000000000000) are all valid and equivalent?

Comment: When you have no scientific notation and fill out everything with 0's like you describe, the only problem is the minus sign. Does your data have a certain range ? Max value ? You can circumvent the sorting issue with the minus sign by e.g. adding 1000000000 to your data, sort it and subtract that value when you report the values.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, it can be assumed.

Comment: Is the requirement that the strings must sort in the same order as the doubles the only requirement on the strings? (or e.g. be human readable (however that is defined), have a max length, ...?)

Comment: @nielsen We could add the requirement that has a max length of 100 char

Answer (score 1):

The following function converts "normal" doubles into a string in the form `<sign><exponent><mantissa>` where sign is either N (negative) or P (positive). The mantissa precision is set to 17 decimal digits and can easily be adjusted.

Special cases (including 0) are handled in the bottom of the function.

**Update**: Added reversing the order of negative numbers. Since negative numbers need to be sorted with the largest absolute value first, we have to construct the 9's complement of the exponent and mantissa. Furthermore, the negative exponents must come after the positive exponents for negative numbers. Hence, the lower case "n" is used for negative exponents for negative numbers since that comes after uppercase "P" by its ASCII value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>

std::string doubleToString(double x)
{
    if(std::isnormal(x))
    {
        int e;
        double m = std::frexp(x, &e);
        std::stringstream s;
        bool negative = (m < 0.0);
        s << (negative ? "N" : "P"); // "N" for negative; "P" for positive
        s << "E"; // Exponent
        if(e >= 0)
        {
            s << "P" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5) << e;
        }
        else
        {
            s << ((negative) ? "n" : "N") << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5) << -e;
        }
        s << "M" << std::setprecision(17) << std::fixed << std::fabs(m); // Mantissa
        std::string result;
        if(negative)
        {   // Convert numbers to 9's complement
            std::string tmp = s.str();
            for(auto c = tmp.begin(); c != tmp.end(); c++)
            {
                if(isdigit(*c))
                {
                    result += ('9' - ((*c) - '0'));
                }
                else
                {
                    result += *c;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = s.str();
        }
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        switch(std::fpclassify(x))
        {
            case FP_NAN: return "xNaN";
            case FP_ZERO: return "O";  // "O" is placed between "N" (negative) and "P" (positive)
            case FP_INFINITE: return (x>0) ? "PInf":"N Inf"; // The space after "N" goes before any number
            case FP_SUBNORMAL: // Fall through
            default:
                return "xUnknown";
        }
    }
}
```

Example outputs:

```
1.500000:  PEP00001M0.75000000000000000                                                                                                   
0.500000:  PEP00000M0.50000000000000000                                                                                                   
-0.005000: NEn99992M9.35999999999999998                                                                                                  
-0.500000: NEP99999M9.49999999999999999                                                                                                  
0.005000:  PEN00007M0.64000000000000001                                                                                                   
0.000000:  O                                                                                                                              
3.141593:  PEP00002M0.78539816339744828                                                                                                   
inf:       PInf                                                                                                                                
-inf:      N Inf                                                                                                                              
nan:       xNaN
```

Answer (score 0):

We know FP numbers have three parts: sign, exponent, mantissa.

The sign has to come first, because all negative numbers sort before +0.0

The exponent has to come next, because all positive numbers with exponent N sort before exponent N+1. Naturally, all possible values of the exponent need a string representation such that they're ordered correctly, but the exponent is an integer. Therefore, zero-prefixing works.

The mantissa has to come last. It's also an integer, so the same zero-prefixing works.

`NaN` is unordered, so it doesn't matter where it would end up. `+INF` and `-INF` look like they'd work if you assume IEEE754 (iec559) representations.

Comment: One detail: In ASCII `+` comes before `-` and we need the opposite. Maybe switching `+` and `-` for `P` and `M` respectively could be an option. Also, the exponent is a signed integer.

Comment: @nielsen: I didn't mention _how_ you'd represent the fields, except for the possible zero-padding. As an example, you could also take the Base-64 encoding of the binary representation of an IEEE754 `double`. It has the fields in the order I mentioned, and also as fixed-width.

Comment: Zero-padding would not be applicable for the Base-64 encoding of an IEEE754 value if that is what we go for. Anyway, the Base-64 encoding would have the same problem with the sign since 0 is positive and 1 is negative, i.e. negative numbers would come after positive numbers. So the first bit would have to be inverted.